# Sympy solveset showing imaginary solutions

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to solve the equation -

f(x) = x^3 - 4x^2 + 1

using sympy and despite the graph of the plot showing real roots, my code outputs imaginary roots

I have tried changing the domain of the variable to real but that doesn't seem to work

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex=True)
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
solveset((x**3 - 4*(x**2) + 1),x, domain=S.Reals)
```

Expected output using wolfram alpha is, x≈ -0.47283, 0.53740,  3.9345 and the output from the above sympy code is this https://ibb.co/bbwzYRb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your cited page but obtain a Union of a Set and an Intersection. Looks like `Intersection` doesn't know that it should ignore imaginary parts on the roots. Evaluating `solve` results with `chop=True` will work:

```
>>> [i.n(2, chop=True) for i in solve(x**3 - 4*(x**2) + 1)]
[0.54, -0.47, 3.9]
```

Comment: Thanks, the provided solution works, will have to read more documentation to figure out why

Comment: Although it is possible to know how many real roots there are for a given cubic it might not be possible to represent those without using imaginary numbers (see casus irredicibilis). When Intersection computes the numerical values of the roots to see whether they are reals or not, my guess is that it computes the values, sees imaginary parts *that have no precision* but concludes that the imaginary parts are real and rejects them. There is no information stored with Intersection to tell it how many roots are real so the best it could do, I think, is just leave the results unevaluated.